# How to apply FastAPI Middleware on "non-async def" endpoints?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, fastapi, middleware

According to https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/, we could apply a FastAPI Middleware on `async def` endpoints.

Currently I have several `non-async def` endpoints, how to apply FastAPI Middleware on `non-async def` endpoint? If I still register an `async` Middleware, will it work for the `non-async def` endpoint ?

For example:

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    response.headers["X-Process-Time"] = str(process_time)
    return response
```

Will the Middleware work properly if `call_next` is a non-async def method ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, because the call_next will be a coroutine created by Starlette. Your “sync” endpoints are executed in a thread pool and ran as async methods/functions.

Comment: @JarroVGIT Thank you for replying. Just curious where could I find the tutorial of `“sync” endpoints are executed in a thread pool and ran as async methods/functions`. It is a new concept for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coroutine is created based on any synchronous function. So yes, this will work fine for you. You can read more about this [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions).